# How to send a jquery value to the controller..?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I have in the view a dropdownlist that I handle with jquery.  I need to know how to send the selected Item of the dropdown to the controller, because I need this information to do a specific action, could anybody help me..??

Here's the javascript code I tried, but it doesn't work:

```
  $("#BtnPassType").click(function () {
                    var formData = $("#displaydropdown option:selected").val();

                    $.post("/EquipodeRed/Prueba/", { tipo: formData }, 
                    function (data) {
                        alert(data.toString());
                    }, "text");

                });
```

Here's the HTML code of the button:

```
<input type="button" id="BtnPassType" value="Send Type" />
```

And here's the Controller Code

```
public String Prueba(string tipo)
        {
            string ubic = "Esta es la Ubicacion del equipo de tipo :";
            return ubic + tipo;
        }
```

I appreciate some help, thanks in advance.
Regards.

Answer (score 1):

You AJAX call seems fine. You could simplify it like this:

```
$('#BtnPassType').click(function () {
    var formData = $('#displaydropdown').val();
    $.post('/EquipodeRed/Prueba', { tipo: formData }, function (data) {
        alert(data);
    });
    // make sure you return false to cancel any default actions of this button
    return false;
});
```

Also it is better to have controller actions return action results:

```
public ActionResult Prueba(string tipo)
{
    return Content("The selected type is :" + tipo);
}
```

And of course avoid hardcoding urls in your javascripts, always use url helpers:

```
$.post('@Url.Action("Prueba", "EquipodeRed")', { tipo: formData }, function (data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

Comment: Hi Darin..!! I tried with your suggestions but it doesn't work, I need to get the Id of the selected item in the dropdown for make a database query to fill another jquery plugin, but doesn't work, during the debug doesn't shows errors.... I don't have any clue about what I'm doing wrong... I hope you can help me.... thanks in advance... Regards..!!